# Removing all unused sound objects from android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android project that contains a lot of unused sound resources

Is there any way to automatically remove all unused resources from an android project including sounds ?

Comment: Use [Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking).

Answer (score 2):

- Lint can tell you what resources are unused so you can remove them: invoke via Android Studio or by hand: `lint --check UnusedResources <PROJECT PATH>`
- you can open generated `R.java` file and look at resources - unused will be highlighted same way any other unused member is (but be careful with it, only Java references count, but not layout ones, or reference by resource name via code)
- you can use https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover (based on lint report)